# Ruby on Rails default value on form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey, need a little help here.

I have two models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs
end
```

and

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

When i do migration i put

```
class CreateJobs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :jobs do |t|
      t.references :user
.....
```

What should i put on my jobs/new action for user_id?

I use resfull_authentication, so i have current_user helper.

```
<% form_for(@job) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <p>
 User:
 <%= f.label current_user.login %> #works fine for me! current_user.id works fine two!

     ??????????????? But what should i put for value???????

  </p>


  <p>
    <%= f.label :filename %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :filename %>
  </p>
```

Should i put current_user.id on controller? If so, how ?

Please help! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit after more info:**

In your controller, do something like:

```
@user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
@job = Job.new(params[:job])
@user.jobs << job
```

**Original answer:**

You could have something like:

```
<%= f.collection_select :user_id, User.find(:all, :order => "name ASC"),
        :id, :name, {:include_blank => true} %>
```

This'll give you a dropdown with user names in alphabetical order.

Comment: That's cool, thanks. An what if i want to put there exact current user ?

Comment: I guess I don't quite understand your question. What exactly are you trying to do with this form?

Comment: When i create a new Job, i want to put current user id (the id of user who creates a Job) to user_id. So that way i will know then, who create that job. I even don't need to see that on my view. That value have to puts there automatically

Answer (score 2):

```
def new
  @job = current_user.jobs.new
end

def create
  @job = current_user.jobs.build(params[:job])
  if @job.save
    redirect_to @job
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

When the job gets created, the user_id column will automatically be assigned to the current_user id.

Is this what you're trying to do?

Answer (score -1):

You can use hidden field tag.

View:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'user_id', current_user.id %>
```

Comment: Putting this as hidden tags allows anyone to modify the value before submitting the form